# SymPy automatically processes expressions

Tags: python, latex, sympy, tex

I have been using SymPy to convert expressions into latex (to then be rendered by Matplotlib). e.g.

```
from sympy import latex, sympify
from sympy.abc import x

str = '2*x + 3*x'

TeX = latex(sympify(str))
```

The problem is that it automatically processes the expression, so 2*x + 3*x automatically becomes 5*x etc; which is not what I want (don't ask!).

Comment: Maybe you should just copy your original string...

Comment: I really want the equation to render with proper fraction lines, root symbols etc. Thanks for that though!

Comment: So you simply want typesetting? In which case a CAS like SymPy is probably not appropriate... Maybe [some sort of LaTeX equation editor](http://www.google.com/search?q=latex+equation+editor)? If this is not what you want, can you edit your question to be more specific?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sympy's `Add` class handles the addition of symbols. You can provide a keyword argument to stop the automatic collection of terms.

```
from sympy import Add
from sympy.abc import x

eq = Add(2*x, 3*x, evaluate=False)

# this will print: 2*x + 3*x
print eq
```

This may not be exactly what you want based on your reply to phimuemue's comment.

Comment: My aim is that school-age students can enter mathematical expressions that the program will render. So, yes, this is not quite what I need, but thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Actually when you call sympify(str) it tries to parse expression and convert them into the default classes. In this case `Add(2*x,2*x)` will be called (with default parameter evalaute=True) so this became `5*x`. If you want to avoid it either you have to call `Add(2*x,3*x,evaluate=False)` or use some global variable and check in **init** method of  AssocOp class in core-> operation.py

i am doing this

```
 try:
        import __builtin__
        evaluate_expr=__builtin__.evaluate_expr
    except AttributeError ,ex:
        pass 

    if ((not options.pop('evaluate', True)) or (evaluate_expr==False)) :
```

**Note - sympy use caching for function , so if you call same function (say :`sympy("2*x+3*x")` )two times .1st time with your gloabl variable `evalute=True` and 2nd time with `evaluate=False`. in both cases becuase of caching you will get same result.
So you need to update methods like (**add** ,**mul** ) in core->expr class. something like below

```
def __add__(self, other):
        #simplifychange:
        evaluate_expr=self.get_evaluate()
        return Add(self, other,evaluate=evaluate_expr)
```

But i will suggest it would be better if you dont use evaluate=False. Behavior of sympy will change dramatically. problems like i was facing in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079892/python-sympy-issue-with-expression-equality-check-when-evaluate-false)

Comment: Good to know that sympy relies on auto-processing for testing equality! Time-saver!

Answer (score -1):

> >>> import re
>
> >>> re.sub("(^|[\(\[\{\+\-\*/ ,\:=])(\-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)", "\\1Dummy('\\2')", '2*x + 3*x')
>
> "Dummy('2')*x + Dummy('3')*x"
>
> >>> eval(_)
>
> 2⋅x + 3⋅x
>
> >>> latex(_)
>
> '2 x + 3 x'