# Python- Sympy Issue with expression equality check when evaluate=False

Tags: python, sympy

In my project I have to use `evaluate=false` at the time when i am creating any `Add` or `Mul` objects. In this case I am facing a problem when I apply equality checks on these objects. The issue is because of the ordering of the arguments.

Please consider the example below:

```
k2=Mul(*[x,y,2],evaluate=False)
k1=Mul(*[x,2,y],evaluate=False)
print k1==k2
```

The result is `false` as `k2.args` are `(x,y,2)` and `k1.args` are `(x,2,y)`.
So, while the comparison checks for tuple equality it returns `false`.
Is there any way I can get the wanted result?

Also, if I put some operation on tuples (like reversing the order and then checking), it fails in the cases when `k1` and `k2` are formed from different `Mul` objects (like when `k1.args` = `2*x,y` and `k2.args` = `2*y,x`)

I can't use sorting here , as in this case `Add([x+y,z],evaluate=False)` and `Add([x+z,y],evaluate=False)` will be two different expressions. Also if i use `evalaute=True`, in this case `Add([x+y],x])` and `Add([2*x+y])` will be the same, which i don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found one work around.

in Add/Mul classes at the expression formation 
flatten all arguments using below code

```
   flatten_args = []
            for arg in args:
                if (arg.__class__==cls):
                    flatten_args.extend(arg.args)
                else:
                    flatten_args.append(arg)

            obj = Expr.__new__(cls, *flatten_args)
```

and at the time of equality check ,i am putting one extra check
sort the args list first `arg_list.sort()` and than compare two lists

Answer (score 1):

Mul doesn't know that x and y both represent scalars. Matrix multiplication depends on the order of the arguments so in your example k1 and k2 are not necessarily equal. 
If you know that in your program x and y will always be scalars (or some other type of value where multiplication is commutative and associative) there may be a way to factor out the constants from each term, compare the constants and compare a sorted list of terms.

Comment: i posted this question so that some one can suggest me that way to compare. and yes my multiplication are always commutative. please see edited section in my question

Answer (score 0):

Does the following help you?

```
print simplify(k1 - k2) == 0 # True
print k1 == k2 # Still False
```

Comment: not actually. as in this case "x+2y" and "x+y+y" are same .i dont want sympy to perform any operations. though i have found one workaround . where i am first flattening all arguments than sorting it and than comparing.