# Sympy bug? Even with `evaluate=False` equations are automatically processed

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy, evaluation

Consider the following sympy code:

```
from sympy import Add
from sympy.abc import x

t1 = 2+2*x
t2 = x
myeq = sp.UnevaluatedExpr(Add(sp.UnevaluatedExpr(t1), sp.UnevaluatedExpr(t2), evaluate=False))

# BUG! Will print: x + 2*x + 2
# Yet it should print: 2+2*x+x
print(myeq)
```

This code snippet was adapted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6453329/2051959) answer. There the terms are simpler, so `Add` preserved the order. But how can I make `Add` preserve the order in this case as well?

(Remark: If we change the terms to `t1=x` and `t2=x**2` my approach with using the `sp.UnevaluatedExpr` works, but the original answer that did not have those terms does not. Alas, for my specific case, not even using `sp.UnevaluatedExpr` works.)

Comment: @OlivierMelançon No, it does. check out my edit, where I am able to suppress some internatl evaluation (this solves the previous problem, before I edited my question and introduced different terms, but not the current one)

Comment: @OlivierMelançon I don't understand exactly the question. use `evaluate=False`, according to the documentation, should prevent `Add` to change the input. Yet this is exactly what it does (in this edit and in all the previous edits; the difference between them being only that I manage to find a workaround for the previous edits), so I would qualify it as faulty behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This is not a bug...

... but more a missing feature. All of it being documented.

Here is what SymPy means by [unevaluated](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/manipulation.html#prevent-expression-evaluation).

> By *unevaluated* it is meant that the value inside of it will not
>   interact with the expressions outside of it to give simplified
>   outputs.

In your example, the terms `2*x` and `x` were not simplified, as is expected.

### Order of input

What you are seeing is SymPy not preserving the order in which you input your terms. This is [documented under the expression tree section](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/manipulation.html#understanding-expression-trees).

> The arguments of the commutative operations `Add` and `Mul` are stored in
>   an arbitrary (but consistent!) order, which is independent of the
>   order inputted.

This should not be a problem since `Add` and `Mul` are commutative.

Although, if for some reason you want to preserve the order of input due to non-commutativity of multiplication, you can do so.

> In SymPy, you can create noncommutative Symbols using `Symbol('A',
>   commutative=False)`, and the order of multiplication for
>   noncommutative Symbols is kept the same as the input)

As for now, there does not seem to be non-commutative addition.